# Generic Method fails with selector

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics

orderselector:

```
Func<Model.Candidate, object> orderselector = p => p.UpdateDate;
```

SelectListbyDesc method call:

```
helper.Result= Model.GeneralDataAccessor.SelectListbyDesc<Model.Candidate,
OrgCandidateSearch.Result, object>(predicate, selector, orderselector, 
(model.PageNo - 1) * model.Count, model.Count);
```

I would like the helper.Result to have the result in descending order based on `UpdateDate`.
But the result is in ascending order. `SelectListbyDesc` works fine for anything else.

Can I write sth like `(p=>p.UpdateDate).OrderByDescending()` in the first place?

SelectListbyDesc:

```
 public static List<T2> SelectListbyDesc<T1, T2, T3>(Expression<Func<T1, bool>> predicate, Func<T1, T2> selector, Func<T1, T3> keySelector,
        int skip = 0, int take = 0, bool addRelationalProperties = true)
        where T1 : class
    {
        string typeName = GetTypeName<T1>();
        using (ObjectContext context = GetContext())
        {
            ObjectSet<T1> objectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<T1>();
            if (addRelationalProperties)
            {
                if (take == 0)
                    return Include(objectSet, GetIncludeProperties<T1>()).Where<T1>(predicate).OrderBy<T1, T3>(keySelector).Select<T1, T2>(selector).ToList<T2>();
                else
                    return Include(objectSet, GetIncludeProperties<T1>()).Where<T1>(predicate).OrderBy<T1, T3>(keySelector).Skip(skip).Take(take)
                        .Select<T1, T2>(selector).ToList<T2>();
            }
            else
            {
                if (take == 0)
                    return objectSet.Where<T1>(predicate).OrderByDescending<T1, T3>(keySelector).Select<T1, T2>(selector).ToList<T2>();
                else
                    return objectSet.Where<T1>(predicate).OrderByDescending<T1, T3>(keySelector).Take(take).Select<T1, T2>(selector).ToList<T2>();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume `OrderBy` is called inside `SelectListbyDesc` and you cannot change that, right?

Comment: `SelectListByDesc` is a custom method - how is anyone supposed to know what it does?

Comment: @AntP but it sorts anything in descending order apart from this

Comment: SelectListbyDesc was added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if there is no way to change the way items are ordered, there is a way to change to sorting value to something ordering.

```
Func<Model.Candidate, object> orderselector = p => DateTime.MaxValue - (p.UpdateDate - DateTime.MinValue);
```

Logic is like this: `p.UpdateDate - DateTime.MinValue` gives a time span for `p.UpdateDate`, and subtracting it from `DateTime.MaxValue` gives us the `DateTime` instance opposite to what we had initially.

However note that this looks more like a hack than a real solution. Real solution is of course to implement proper conditional ordering in SelectListbyDesc`.

Comment: Worked as expected. Thanks!